# Strange problem with reading and writing a plist file

Tags: objective-c, iphone, plist

I have an application that read info from I plist file. To do it I use this code below:

```
  NSData *plistData;  
    NSString *error;  
    NSPropertyListFormat format;  
    id plist;  
    localizedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"plist"];  
    plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localizedPath];   
    
    plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];  
    if (!plist) {  
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist from file '%s', error = '%s'", [localizedPath UTF8String], [error UTF8String]);  
        [error release];  
    }  
    
    
    
   
    NSString *tel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",[plist objectForKey:@"number"]];
    NSURL *telephoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tel];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telephoneURL];
```

And to write it I use this code:

```
- (IBAction) saveSetting:(id)sender{
    
    NSData *plistData;  
    NSString *error;  
    NSPropertyListFormat format;  
    id plist;  
    
    NSString *localizedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"plist"];  
    plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localizedPath];   
    
    plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:&format errorDescription:&error];  
    if (!plist) {  
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist from file '%s', error = '%s'", [localizedPath UTF8String], [error UTF8String]);  
        [error release];  
    }  
    
    NSLog([plist objectForKey:@"message"]);
    [plist setValue:textMex.text forKey:@"message"];
    NSLog([plist objectForKey:@"message"]);
    
    NSLog([plist objectForKey:@"number"]);
    [plist setValue:textNumero.text forKey:@"number"];
    NSLog([plist objectForKey:@"number"]);
    
    [plist setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"firstTime"];
    
    [plist writeToFile:localizedPath atomically:YES];
    
    [self aggiorna];
    
    [settingScreen removeFromSuperview];
    
}
```

Now I have a big problem, tha app works properly in all my developer device and in the simulator and the app reads and writes the file properly.

I submit the app on the Apple store but others user can't read/write this file.

Why is this?

Comment: Did Apple reject it, or did they accept it but users have problems?  Do you know what the error message says?

Comment: Why not simply using an NSArray or an NSDictionary to read and write the property list? It's like ten times easier. WTP?

Comment: Why not use NSUserDefaults? It's meant for settings and is essentially a plist.

Comment: @WTP can you post same example? thanks

Comment: Are you sure you didn't received any error when you called saveSetting method?  That code should not work at all.

Comment: @Moshe can you link me some example? Can i config NSUserDefaults like my settings.plist?

Comment: @paul_1991 Write: `[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:…stuff here…] writeToURL:myPlistURL atomically:YES];` | Read: `NSDictionary *settingsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:myPlistURL];`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't write back to the application bundle. You will have to copy the original plist file to the documents directory or any other writable location before it can be written to.

**An example**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString libraryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString plistPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];

// Checks if the file exists at the writable location.
if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath] ) {
    NSString *masterFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Try to copy the master file to the writable location
    NSError *error;
    if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:masterFilePath toPath:plistPath error:&error] ) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); 
        // Serious error.
    }
}

...
// Ready for use.
NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak, how can I do that? So problem is that the file settings.plist is present in the app directory of other user but they can write that, right? How I can fix the permission? thanks

Comment: Try to read the file from the Library directory and if you find that the file doesn't exist, copy the master file (the settings.plist that ships with your app) into the Library directory. Now start using the file to read and write.

Comment: thanks deepack, where is located the library directory? How can i copy this file in the library when the app is starting?

Comment: Added an example. You can either do it when the application has started like in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or you can check and copy it lazily only when needed.

Comment: @deepak: could you help me out with something